# LWC lightning datatable custom labels

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, datatable, customlabel

How to use custom labels inside label of LWC Lightning datatable.
I'm unable to find any resource or documentation to use custom label instead of HardCoded values inside js controller of LWC cmp.
Any suggestion would be helpful.
I need to use custom-label in place of hardcoded 'Label'.

```
const columns = [
    { label: 'Label', fieldName: 'name' }
]
```

I tried {label.labelreference}/{label-labelreference} -- not working in LWC js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to import each label:

```
import labelreference from '@salesforce/label/c.labelreference';
```

and then you can reference the label in e.g. the columns:

```
const columns = [
    { label: labelreference, fieldName: 'name' }
];
```

Comment: Thank you @KeithC for reply. It worked